# How to deploy reports in SQL Server Reporting Services tool if credentials are not known?

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008

Assuming that I have a report which I want to deploy into the server it is asking for the credentials which I don't know. How is it possible to continue with the deploying?

Comment: Ask someone who can tell you - if you need credentials, and don't know them - that's really the only thing you can do......

Answer (score 2):

You really need those credentials. The sames ones you you use to log into SSRS management should work

Answer (score 0):

You can use the client computer user on the server if it's allowed to process.